# How to set unique hasMany relations based class properties?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, database-schema, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have two domain classes:

```
class Book {
  String name

  static hasMany = [articles: Article]
}   


class Article {
  String name

  static belongsTo = [book: Book]
}
```

I want to validate that a book does have only unique articals in terms of the article name property. In other words: there must be no article with the same name in the same book.
How can I ensure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a custom validator on your `Book` class (see [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html)).

A possible implementation can look like this:

```
static constraints = {
    articles validator: { articles, obj -> 
        Set names = new HashSet()
        for (Article article in articles) {
            if (!names.add(article.name)) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

In this example I am using a `java.util.Set` to check for duplicate names (`Set.add()` returns `false` if the same name is added twice).

You can trigger the validation of an object with `myBookInstance.validate()`.